# Factory Post Method in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a question. In my project at school, I have a factory for control `$http.post`. And in controller, I use this factory for call API. But I don't know how to controller the params for this.

**Example 1:**

```
//url for post note: xxxxx.com/api/order?**userID**=1

//**param**: note(string)
```

**Example 2:**

```
//url for post note: xxxxx.com/api/room?**roomID**=1

//**param**: note(string), serviceID(number)
```

What the best way for function post in the factory know "userID" or "roomID" and params of each api?

This is a factory and controller:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f19xt3qr/)

Comment: Are you using ui.router or ngRoute?

Comment: @Kauffee000 yes I using ngRoute